# How to deploy into a Service Fabric cluster using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-cli, azure-container-registry, azure-service-fabric-mesh

I want to deploy a container image onto Service Fabric cluster running on Azure. I have already pushed image on Azure Container Registry. Using command line interface, how can I deploy container image into Service Fabric Cluster running on Azure?

I looked at [sfctl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cli) command but could not find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is by using [sfctl compose create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-sfctl-compose#sfctl-compose-create).
With this command you deploy a container to the cluster by using a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file.

[Getting started...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/scripts/sfctl-upgrade-application)